# Not able to access the magento api installed from AMPPS

Tags: magento-1.9, api

You don't have permission to access `/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2/create/`
on this server

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please specify the magento version you are facing issue in.

Comment: version 1.9.3.3